# Can't Open Gnome-Control-Center in Ubuntu 18.04 - Some library is missing

Tags: 18.04, gnome-control-center

When I try to start `gnome-control-center` from the command line, I get the following error.

```
$ gnome-control-center
gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libreplace.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libwbclient0`

Comment: Tried `sudo apt install --reinstall libwbclient0` and worked! Thanks @Liso

Comment: @Liso Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question. Here, is it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libwbclient0
```